# How can i know how many numbers that the user wrote the same?

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop

I need to write a function that accepts the length of series(0 and 1) and the user writes the series. The function tells the place of the longest same sun-series.

Example:
The function gets length = 12, and the user writes: 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1
The answer for this one is 4 because the longest combination (four consecutive 1's) starts at 4th place.

Another example:
The length is: 12 and the user inputs : 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 
The answer for this one is 2 (three consecutive 0's starting at position 2—if there are multiple sub-series with same length it returns the first one).

This is what I tried to do:

```
int sameNumbers(int seriaLength)
{
    int i;
    int place=0;
    int num1, num2;
    int sameCount;
    int maxSameCount = 0;

    printf("Please enter the seria: \n");
    scanf("%d",&num1);

    for(i = 1; i < seriaLength; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&num2);
        while(num1 == num2)
        {
            sameCount++;
        }
        if(sameCount > maxSameCount)
        {
            maxSameCount = sameCount;
            place = i;
        }
        scanf("%d",&num1);
    }

    return place;
}
```

Edit:
I need to do this without arrays.

Thanks!!

Comment: `while(num1 == num2) { ... }` will loop forever since neither `num1` nor `num2` are updated inside the loop

Comment: Yes, thanks. But I don't know how to continue :/

Comment: And I need to do this without arrays...

Comment: A requirement like "need to do this without arrays.." should be appended to the post rather than a simple comment.

Comment: You right! Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do what you want.  To understand the logic, see the comments in the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sameNumbers(int seriaLength)
{

    int i, num, previousNum, length = 0, maxLength = 0, start = 0, startOfLongest = 0;

    printf( "Please enter the series: " );

    for( i = 0; i < seriaLength; i++ )
    {
        scanf( "%d", &num );

        if( i > 0 && num == previousNum ) length++;
        else { length = 1; start = i; }  // if the number is not the same as the previous number, record the start of a new sequence here
        if( length > maxLength ) { maxLength = length; startOfLongest = start; } // if we've broken (not equalled) the previous record for longest sequence, record where it happened
        previousNum = num;
    }
    return startOfLongest + 1; //  add 1 because the OP seems to want the resulting index to be 1-based
}

int main( int argc, const char * argv[] )
{
    printf( "%d\n", sameNumbers( 12 ) );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: By the way can i do this question using 2 for loops? It's not a better solution?

Comment: What would be the advantage of a 2-loop solution?

Comment: Don't know.. just asking :)

Comment: I can't think of an advantage to using a more complicated control structure where a simple one works—but "works" depends on the various different ways you foresee using it.  Given the way you stated the problem, a single pass through the sequence is about the simplest and most efficient way I see of doing it.  (If you had to call `sameNumbers` a zillion times, a slight gain in efficiency might be had by stopping early if you know the rest of the sequence isn't long enough to beat the current record.)

Comment: Yea i guess you right. Thank you very much for your time and patience! :)